# Jmeter returns JSESSIONID Cookie expiration time as 0 however browser resturns "Session"

Tags: session, cookies, jmeter, jsessionid

[image]Actually, when I hit a http request through Jmeter then I get values of various cookies as in the attached image and then one of the request responses 500 error.

Also, when I look at these cookies in the browser, these have expiration time value as "Session" and request run fine there.

Moreover, if I manually paste the JSESSIONID in request header of Jmeter. It is fine there too.

I tried various methods to pass it to subsequent requests : -

a) Http Cookie Manager
b) Beanshell processors for sharing variables.
c) WDS to get the session id and pass it.

etc.

Here I am attaching an image for browser references also.

It will be great if someone could help in the above problem.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) chapter:

> ```
> GET /sample_page.html HTTP/2.0
> Host: www.example.org
> Cookie: yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry
> ```

> **Session cookies**

> The cookie created above is a session cookie: it is deleted when the client shuts down, because it didn't specify an Expires or Max-Age directive. However, web browsers may use session restoring, which makes most session cookies permanent, as if the browser was never closed.

Refer to the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.1) to learn how browsers should handle "Expires" attribute:

> **5.2.1.  The Expires Attribute**

> If the attribute-name case-insensitively matches the string
> "Expires", the user agent MUST process the cookie-av as follows.

> Let the expiry-time be the result of parsing the attribute-value as
> cookie-date (see [Section 5.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.1)).

> If the attribute-value failed to parse as a cookie date, ignore the
> cookie-av.

> If the expiry-time is later than the last date the user agent can
> represent, the user agent MAY replace the expiry-time with the last
> representable date.

Also be informed that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details

Comment: Well, the issue here is that the response from server for the request comprises - a) Expiration time 0 b) path as "/some-path". Moreover, the cookie is http-only. Now, the methods like - "getCookies()" from WebDriver and "document.cookie" from Javascript are not helping as they can't reach path other than root. On the other hand if I hit this request from the tools like Jmeter, 0 expires time is returned which means it becomes invalid as soon as it reaches the client since it is not a browser which can maintain the session. And that is why I see Session as the Expiration value of this cookie.